# Rhetorical effects of future tense when describing past event

Tags: present-tense, future

> Just before 2 a.m., as it prepared for its return to Earth, the Crew
> Dragon jettisoned what SpaceX calls the “trunk” section of the
> spacecraft — the cylindrical compartment below the gumpdrop-shaped
> capsule. The trunk **will** burn up in the atmosphere. Five minutes
> after the trunk **is** detached, the capsule fired its thrusters for
> about 16 minutes to drop out of orbit. Once it was low enough in
> Earth’s atmosphere, parachutes deployed to gently lower the capsule
> into the sea.

As I read a New York Times article about the return to Earth of four astronauts in a SpaceX capsule, I came across the sentences above. In chronicling a string of past events, the author applied the future or present tense, perhaps aiming to create a vivid description of some sort.

But as a non-native speaker, I found it difficult to point out precisely what effects this rhetorical device had since I was a bit baffled by the sudden appearance of the future and present tense.

Could you tell me about exactly what effects this rhetorical technique has and how you, as a native speaker, feel when this future-tense sentence suddenly appears?

Comment: This is sort of okay: *The trunk will burn up in the atmosphere*. It indicates that the trunk will eventually burn up, but that its eventual burning is not a part of this narrative timeline. But this seems like an editing error: *Five minutes after the trunk is detached*. It should read either: *Five minutes after the trunk was detached* or *Five minutes after the trunk detached*.

Comment: I don't think it's even "sorta" okay! To me, the mixture of tenses here is just *garbage*. I suppose it's feasible that *at time of utterance*, the trunk had detached, *but not yet burned up on re-entry*. But even allowing for that as a real-world possibility (which seems unlikely), the overall text is hopelessly confused about timeframes. It's not a "technique" - it's a "mash-up".

Comment: If I were the copy editor, I would have changed "is" to "was" in this part -- the present tense feels really wrong:
"Five minutes after the trunk is detached, the capsule fired its thrusters for about 16 minutes ..."